# Create user in Kubernetes for kubectl

Tags: json, kubernetes, kubectl, endpoint, rbac

I need to create users to assign them permissions with RBAC, I create them as follows:

```
echo -n "lucia" | base64
bHVjaWE=
echo -n "pass" | base64
cGFzcw==

apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: lucia-secret
type: Opaque
data:
  username: bHVjaWE=
  password: cGFzcw==
```

Or create with:

```
kubectl create secret generic lucia-secret --from-literal=username='lucia',password='pass'
```

I don't know how to continue

```
USER_NICK=lucia

kubectl config set-credentials $USER_NICK \
    --username=lucia \
    --password=pass

kubectl get secret lucia-secret -o json | jq -r '.data["ca.crt"]' | base64 -d > ca.crt

endpoint=`kubectl config view -o jsonpath="{.clusters[?(@.name == \"$name\")].cluster.server}"`

kubectl config set-cluster cluster-for-lucia \
  --embed-certs=true \
  --server=$endpoint \
  --certificate-authority=./ca.crt

kubectl config set-context context-lucia \
  --cluster=cluster-for-lucia \
  --user=$USER_NICK \
  --namespace=default
```

ca.crt is null

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 44):

As kubernetes [docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/) and Articles uses certificate to create or authenticate users for kubectl client. However there is one easy way to do it by using ServiceAccount. One can use ServiceAccount as a group to provide RBAC control authentication and it is very easy and descriptive. Here are the steps.
All the steps i am executing is in `default` namespace. I am going to create a pod readonly user which can get,list,watch any pod in all namespaces.

- Create a ServiceAccount, say 'readonlyuser'.

  `kubectl create serviceaccount readonlyuser`
- Create cluster role, say 'readonlyuser'.

  `kubectl create clusterrole readonlyuser --verb=get --verb=list --verb=watch --resource=pods`
- Create cluster role binding, say 'readonlyuser'.

  `kubectl create clusterrolebinding readonlyuser --serviceaccount=default:readonlyuser --clusterrole=readonlyuser`
- Now get the token from secret of ServiceAccount we have created before. we will use this token to authenticate user.

  `TOKEN=$(kubectl describe secrets "$(kubectl describe serviceaccount readonlyuser | grep -i Tokens | awk '{print $2}')" | grep token: | awk '{print $2}')`
- Now set the credentials for the user in kube config file. I am using 'vikash' as username.

  `kubectl config set-credentials vikash --token=$TOKEN`
- Now Create a Context say podreader. I am using my clustername 'kubernetes' here.

  `kubectl config set-context podreader --cluster=kubernetes --user=vikash`
- Finally use the context .

  `kubectl config use-context podreader`

And that's it. Now one can execute `kubectl get pods --all-namespaces`. One can also check the access by executing as given:

```
~ : $ kubectl auth can-i get pods --all-namespaces
yes
~ : $ kubectl auth can-i create pods
no
~ : $ kubectl auth can-i delete pods
no
```

Comment: Is there any documentation available for this approach??

Answer (score 22):

In this guide you can find how to configure a user for your cluster: https://docs.bitnami.com/kubernetes/how-to/configure-rbac-in-your-kubernetes-cluster/#use-case-1-create-user-with-limited-namespace-access

Long story short:

- Create certificates for the user
- Create a certificate sign request
- Sign the certificate with the cluster certificate authority
- Create a configuration for your user
- Add RBAC rules for this user or its group

Regarding the `ca.crt`, you need to find it in your master host.

Edited: In the case of GKE, check here https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/iam-integration

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I know that entry, but the problem is that I can not find the ca.key, I'm using GKE with container-vm. It's the file --client-ca-file=XXXX?

Comment: The only thing I can not find is the ca.key in my cluster GKE.

Comment: In the case of GKE it seems to work like this: https://cloud.google.com/container-engine/docs/iam-integration

Comment: @JavierSalmeron I have set up kubernetes on rancher. can you please help me find the ca.crt?

Answer (score 0):

A little late update for what worked for me.
I needed also to filter out by namespaces, to give developers read-only access to main app resources, but not nodes, secrets, ingress-controllers, ingress or other namespaces.

Modify and apply the follwing YAML:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: sa-reader
  namespace: default

---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: reader-cr
rules:
- verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]
  resources: 
  - namespaces
  - services
  - endpoints
  - pods
  - deployments
  - configmaps
  - jobs
  - cronjobs
  - daemonsets
  - statefulsets
  - replicasets
  - persistentvolumes
  apiGroups: ["","apps","batch"]
- verbs: ["create", "delete"]
  resources: ["pods"]
  apiGroups: [""]

---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: read-tuxerrante-pods-rb
  namespace: tuxerrante
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: sa-reader
  namespace: default
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: reader-cr
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io

---
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: RoleBinding
metadata:
  name: read-tuxerrante-round-pods-rb
  namespace: tuxerrante-round
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: sa-reader
  namespace: default
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: reader-cr
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

```sh
# THIS WILL APPEND CONFIGURATIONS TO YOUR CURRENT KUBECONFIG
$ TOKEN=$(kubectl describe -n default secrets "$(kubectl describe -n default serviceaccount sa-reader | grep -i Tokens | awk '{print $2}')" | grep token: | awk '{print $2}')
$ kubectl config set-credentials reader-user --token=$TOKEN
$ kubectl config set-context cluster-reader --cluster=cluster-svil --user=reader-user

# I PREFER TO COPY THE PREVIOUS NEW CONFIG IN A NEW FILE AND THEN USE IT
# 
$ export KUBECONFIG=~/.kube/tuxerrante-reader.kubeconfig
$ kubectl config use-context cluster-reader
$ kubectl auth can-i get pods --all-namespaces
$ kubectl auth can-i create pods
$ kubectl auth can-i delete pods
$ kubectl -n tuxerrante get pods
```