# Run Kubectl in apache

Tags: apache, kubectl

I have this bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

USERNAME=$1
WORKDIR='dir_'$USERNAME

mkdir deployment/$WORKDIR
cat deployment/deploy.yml > deployment/$WORKDIR/deploy.yml

sed -i 's/alopezfu/'$USERNAME'/g' deployment/$WORKDIR/deploy.yml

kubectl apply -f deployment/$WORKDIR/deploy.yml

rm -rf deployment/$WORKDIR/
```

And i use exec funcition in PHP for run.

And i get this messege in /var/log/apache/error.log

> To view or setup config directly use the 'config' command.
>   error: no configuration has been provided, try setting KUBERNETES_MASTER environment variable
>   error: Missing or incomplete configuration info.  Please point to an existing, complete config file:
>
> 1. Via the command-line flag --kubeconfig
>
>    2. Via the KUBECONFIG environment variable
>    3. In your home directory as ~/.kube/config

I need help

Comment: From where you are running this PHP script? The source machine has the kubernetes credentials configured? If you are trying to run from a pod, the pod has a service account that allow run this command?

Comment: The script runs on the master node of the cluster, and if I run the script with my user, the one I used to create the cluster, there is no problem the problem is when it is run from apache with the user www-data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are running the script as a diferent user, you need to "tell" to `kubectl` where is the configuration file.

This can be done setting the variable `KUBECONFIG` in your environment.

Supposing the kubernetes `config` file is in the dir `/var/www/` with the correct permission to be readable, you can configure your php script like this:

```php
<?php
$kubeconfig = "/var/www/config"; // The config file

putenv("KUBECONFIG=$kubeconfig"); // set the environment variable KUBECONFIG

$output = shell_exec("KUBECONFIG=$kubeconfig ; kubectl get pods -A"); // Runs the command 

echo "<pre>$output</pre>"; // and return the expected output.
?>
```

Please be aware that:

> - **Setting certain environment variables may be a potential security breach.**

Some actions that should mitigate the impacts:

> - Make sure your config file is safe and not reachable from the browser;
> - Consider to create a serviceAccount with limited permissions;

[Here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/kubectl/cheatsheet/#kubectl-context-and-configuration) you can find some useful commands and kubectl tips.

[How to create a service account for kubectl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44948483/create-user-in-kubernetes-for-kubectl)