# How to manage kubectl from another user

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Hi i have a server configured with kubernetes (without using minikube), i can execute kubectl commands without problems, like `kubectl get all`, `kubectl delete pod`, `kubectl delete apply` ...

I would want to know how to allow another user from my server to execute kubectl commands, because if i change to another user and i try to execute `kubectl get all -s localhost:8443` i get:

`Error from server (BadRequest): the server rejected our request for an unknown reason`

I have read the [Kubernetes Authorization](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authorization/) Documentation, but im not sure if it is what im looking for.

Comment: you mean another linux user in the same vm?

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu yes

Comment: @JaumeGarciaSanchez can you tell if the second user should use the same credentials as the first one? If not take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55534445/12257134

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is happening because there is no `kubeconfig` file for the user.You need to have the same kubeconfig file for the other user either in the default location `$HOME/.kube/config` or in any location pointed by `KUBECONFIG` environment variable.

You can copy the existing `kubeconfig` file for the working user to the above location for the non working user.